# Centering matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I want to write a function for centering an input data matrix by multiplying it with the [centering matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix). The function shall subtract the row-wise mean from the input.

My code:

```
import numpy as np

def centering(data):
  n = data.shape()[0]
  centeringMatrix = np.identity(n) - 1/n * (np.ones(n) @ np.ones(n).T)
  data = centeringMatrix @ data


data = np.array([[1,2,3], [3,4,5]])
center_with_matrix(data)
```

But I get a wrong result matrix, it is not centered.

Thanks!

Comment: The task (!) gives exactly the formula that I am using. I have tried the code ``centeringMatrix = np.identity(n) - 1/n * (np.ones(n) @ np.ones(n).T)`` and it resulst in a nxn matrix where the diagonal components are zero. That's the identity, but "shifted".

Comment: Also wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix
It also uses the formula I am using as the centering matrix.

Comment: I updated the formula in my answer. Didn't read the wikipedia page carefully on mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The centering matrix is

```
np.eye(n) - np.ones((n, n)) / n
```

Here is a list of issues in your original formulation:

1. `np.ones(n).T` is the same as `np.ones(n)`. The transpose of a 1D array is a no-op in numpy. If you want to turn a row vector into a column vector, add the dimension explicitly:

   ```
   np.ones((n, 1))
   ```

   OR

   ```
   np.ones(n)[:, None]
   ```
2. The normal definition is to subtract the column-wise mean, not the row-wise, so you will have to transpose and right-multiply the input to get row-wise operation:

   ```
   n = data.shape()[1]
   ...
   data = (centeringMatrix @ data.T).T
   ```
3. Your function creates a new array for the output but does not currently return anything. You can either return the result, or perform the assignment in-place:

   ```
   return (centeringMatrix @ data.T).T
   ```

   OR

   ```
   data[:] = (centeringMatrix @ data.T).T
   ```

   OR

   ```
   np.matmul(centeringMatrix, data.T, out=data.T)
   ```

Comment: Appreciate your help! But there is one error in your answer. It has to be ``data = (centeringMatrix @ data.T).T``

Comment: @sonsuz-ders. Good call. I got so caught up with transposing the matrix that I forgot to transpose it :)